# How to redraw view layout on rotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a .h file I am using thought my project, I #import the file then use the #define vars to layout my views correctly.

This is what my ScreenSize.h file looks like.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define ScreenWidth ((int) [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)
#define ScreenHeight ((int) [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)

@interface ScreenSize : NSObject

@end
```

I would like to know when the user is browsing to a page and it lays itself out correctly then they decide to rotate it how to update ScreenWidth and ScreenHeight with the correct values, and also to update the current view that's being rotated?

Comment: View controllers automatically change their bounds when the screen changes orientation - why do you need the screen size rather than the view controller size?

Comment: I Need the screen size as all of my xibs are built for iphone so if I look at the viewController size I cannot deploy the app on the iPad.

Comment: why not have separate iPad XIBs? Like @michaels said, the view controllers will normally just give your views a new size on rotation, and then you do a layout based on the new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better implemented as static methods, rather than #defines:

```
+(CGFloat)screenWidth
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)){
        return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    }else{
        [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    }
}

+(CGFloat)screenHeight
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)){
        return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    }else{
        [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    }
}
```

To know when the screen rotates, you can subscribe to `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` using NSNotificationCenter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];
```

And implement the method to handle the notification:

```
-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Layout your views
}
```

Comment: Oh that seems alot better, however I am not sure what you mean by subscribing to the statusbar notification?

Comment: quick question do I add the NSNotification to each viewdidload?

Comment: okay I have finally done some accurate testing on this... got abit lost in my code however I am no getting back the correct values when the rotation happens however for some reason the view is not changing if its already loaded?... so if i go from port to land after the view initally loads it stas in port..

Comment: Do you have auto-rotation enabled?